# uuidv4 updates when new deployments happen in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I need to generate a unique identifier as a env var in my deployment then in pods I have

```
      - name: BUCKET_NAME
    value: test-{{uuidv4}}
```

However whenever I update the deployment I see new value for uuid is being generated.
Is there anyway I can generate a unique ide which wont change if update happens for deployment?

Comment: Is this in the context of a Helm chart?  When (if ever) do you want the UUID regenerated; if you have multiple replicas, should they have the same or different values?

Comment: Need to agree with David Maze comment. Also, could you say more about the use case? Maybe you just need a [Statefulset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/)?